# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. when doing a HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web, httpwebrequest

I am having an issue with my code as I have to verify the status of some websites in order to notify if they are working or not. I can successfully check this for a number of websites, however for a particular one it is always returning 404 Not Found, even though the site is up and I can view it if I try to open the page on the browser, this is my code:

```
 public HttpStatusCode GetHeaders(string url, bool proxyNeeded)
    {

        HttpStatusCode result = default(HttpStatusCode);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "HEAD";

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

        if (proxyNeeded)
        {
            IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", port_number);
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
            request.Proxy = proxy;
        }
        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            result = response.StatusCode;
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                WebResponse resp = e.Response;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    //TODO: capture the exception!!
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The exception does not tell me anything different than "Not Found" which really confuses me as I don't know where else to look.The URL failing is: http://cbprod-app/InterAction/home

If I request the page without setting the proxy, comes back with an "401 Not authorized" as it requires the proxy authentication to be displayed, I am running out of ideas, any suggestion about what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: 1) We can't help you with that URL because it's internal only. There's no TLD, which means it's just a hostname, not a domain. 2) If you're checking for availability, you should strip the path, completely. Hit just the hostname or domain, as the attached server is either up or it isn't. 3) Are you sure it's not actually a 404. Maybe that path really doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for your answer, the site definitely exists, I divided the url and I got an OK response from the hostname, is this good enough to tell if the site is up?